# Is there a way to use mass assignment for everything except for one param in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to lowercase `params[:user][:email]` in my application but currently I'm using `@user = User.new(params[:user])` (which includes the email) in my `def create`.  Is it possible to allow for mass assignment for everything except for a single item?

I know I could just not use mass assignment but I was wondering if this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
class User
  attr_protected :email
end
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
user.email = params[:user][:email].downcase
```

If you want to downcase the email attribute automatically though, you can simply override the `email=` method, which I **strongly** recommend:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def email=(other)
    write_attribute(:email, other.try(:downcase))                                                                                                                                                         
  end
end

Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.5)
irb(main):001:0> User.new({:email => 'Me@you.com'})
=> #<User id: nil, email: "me@you.com", username: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> User.new({:email => nil})
=> #<User id: nil, email: nil, username: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look at attr_protected. This lets you define only the attributes you want to prevent from being mass assigned.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected